# checking condition in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check a multi dimensional array for a key value and print its parent array's another key value. This might confuse a bit. But the below example can make it clear. I have a array like this.

```
Entity Response : Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [type] => FieldTerminology
        [relevance] => 0.709023
        [count] => 4
        [text] => domain name
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [type] => Company
        [relevance] => 0.603375
        [count] => 2
        [text] => Laravel
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [type] => Person
        [relevance] => 0.548389
        [count] => 1
        [text] => M. Naveen Kumar
    )
```

I want to check if any array has a `key [type]` and its `value = "Person"` , then i want to get its value of the `key[text]`. In this case I want to print **M. Naveen Kumar**

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the array to find it. you can use foreach(), array_walk() and so on.

```
$o = [];
array_walk($array, function($v) use（&$o){$v['type'] == 'Person' ? $o[] = $v['text'] : '';});
var_dump($o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$people = array_filter($array, function($each) { return $each['type'] == 'Person'; });
$names = array_map(function($each) { return $each['name']; }, $people);
```

How does this work step by step?

- Filter the array by type using `array_filter`
- Then map to names using `array_map`